# $|E(XY)|\leq M|EY|$ for non-negative $X$ with $|X|\leq M$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Assume a **non-negative** random variables $X$ with $|X|\leq M$.

For any random variable $Y$, do we have that $|E(XY)|\leq M|EY|$?

Comment: @Surb  Thanks for the comment! What bothers me is that Y is not assumed non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

Not true, for instance $X= 1_{[-1,0]}$ on $[-1,1]$ with normalized Lebesgue measure, and $Y$ any odd function, then
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^0 Y(s)\, ds= E(XY), \qquad E(Y)=0.
$$
Now just pick $Y$ such that the left hand side is $\neq 0$.